# Scrolling inside a div

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="js/jquery-1_9_1_js.js"></script> 
      <script>
        $(function() {
          $("#mainDiv").load("two.php"); 
      }); 
  </script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="main" id="mainDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hi, I have above code in one.php. It loads data from two.php into mainDiv. 
The contents of two.php are overlapping out of the div instead of the scrolling inside the div in one.php. Please help me insert a script/code that will scroll the contents inside mainDiv instead of overlapping.

Comment: Add `overflow: auto` and a max/fixed height to your `div`

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
<div id="" style="overflow-y: scroll; height:'your height';">
```

Comment: I have another problem, I want the contents on my mainDiv to refresh automatically on one.php as soon as i save the changes i make in two.php. How can in accomplish this? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  refreshTable();
});

function refreshTable(){
    $('#mainDiv').load('home.php', function(){
       setTimeout(refreshTable, 5000);
    });
}
</script>
```

it will refresh every 5 seconds

Comment: Thanks Jasir alwafaa, I got it. It works! Thanks.. Now i want the div to scroll to the top as new data is entered, how can i achieve this?